# NSArray of NSStrings. Sort by relevance. Best practice

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray, relevance

I have a `NSArray` of `NSString`s.

For example: `@"Good item", @"Very good item", @"The best of the best item"`

Upon searching on `UITextField`, the  user types `@"Very good item"`. I need to sort the source array by relevance and would like to see result as:

```
@"Very good item" <- the best match with the search phrase
@"Good item"
@"The best of the best item"
```

Please suggest me the best way to do it in Objective-C.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to define "relevance" with a degree in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write a method (maybe in an NSString category) that compares two strings and returns a number describing their similarity, using an algorithm that you need to design. A simple algorithm would be splitting each string into words, and counting the number of words the strings have in common.

Sorting is then trivial.